# Finding a target sum from an array of numbers

Tags: c#, math

I want to find a target sum of numbers (quota) from an array of numbers (items) of size 99 with some being 0. The goal is the find the smallest combination of numbers that hit the target, if no such combination exists increase the target by 1 and repeat until a combination is found, the program should return the first match.

I'm familiar with how doing this if there are only 2 numbers needed for the combination but I am not sure how to make it optimal if the total numbers needed is 5+.

Comment: What is the range of the numbers in the array? What is the range of target sums?

Comment: the numbers can be anything between 1 and 200 and target can be anything between 200 and 1000

Comment: In your question you said the array numbers can be zero. Can the array numbers be repeated? If this is a programming challenge, make sure you include all the constraints and details. If all the ai are between 1 and 200, not repeated, and the target is at most 1000, then you need at most 15 numbers, but still have 99 choose 15 = 215337700647490344 possible combinations of 15 elements. I don't think there's any naive solution, and maybe no known feasible solution as optimisation problems like this are known to be 'hard' mathematical problems,

Comment: yes there can be duplicates of a number, you can only use a number once but if its there twice you can use it twice, sorry still new to asking questions

Comment: Most of the time you'll be able to find a sum with a small number of elements, but sometimes you won't. Do you have an example array and target which you could not resolve? I suggest you add it to your question if you have. I wrote a similar program a while ago in c which can find solutions of 6 elements or less from 99 in under a minute. It is quite simple and could be further optimised. What target performance are you looking for?

Comment: Just for fun, see if you can find an 11 element subset (which does exist) that sums to 999 from the following array. 79, 43, 93, 14, 92, 96, 49, 95, 40, 82, 10, 2, 92, 54, 49, 56, 29, 37, 18, 69, 75, 37, 18, 82, 40, 89, 2, 57, 68, 28, 69, 99, 70, 14, 12, 14, 61, 13, 8, 100, 94, 70, 53, 38, 75, 1, 45, 3, 37, 62, 23, 63, 50, 92, 45, 41, 80, 98, 97, 100, 77, 17, 98, 47, 82, 61, 12, 42, 73, 71, 93, 19, 92, 45, 56, 66, 97, 100, 20, 86, 13, 94, 100, 14, 85, 96, 54, 17, 93, 2, 16, 22, 18, 13, 68, 52, 25, 31, 45.

Answer (score 1):

This problem lends itself perfectly to dynamic programming.

First of all, I like to give names to things. Let's call `a[1..99]` your array of numbers and `T` your target.

Let's build a new array, two-dimensional, `s[t, k]`, which represents the best "score" that we can get for target `t` using only the first `k` numbers from array `a`. A "score" is a pair `(y, j)`, where `y` is the smallest sum above `t` that we can get, and `j` is the number of numbers that we need to use to get sum `y`.

The "best" score is the lowest score, where pairs are compared lexicographically, ie `(y1, j1) < (y2, j2)` iff `y1 < y2 or y1 == y2 and j1 < j2`. If you want to encode the score as a single number instead of a pair, you can use number `100 * y + j` to represent pair `(y, j)`; since `j < 100`, this is equivalent.

If it's not possible to get a sum above `t` using only the first `k` numbers of the array, then `s[t,k] = (+infinity, k)`. Instead of `+infinity`, you can use any value `M` greater than the total sum of `a`.

Then it's easy to fill array `s` iteratively, because:

```py
s[0, k] = (0, 0)          for all k         # easy to get target 0
s[t, 0] = (+infinity, 0)  for all t > 0     # cannot get nonzero target without numbers

s[t, k] = min(
    s[t-a[k], k-1] + (a[k], 1),             # use a[k]
    s[t, k-1] + (0, 1)                      # do not use a[k]
)                         if t >= a[k]

s[t, k] = min(
    (a[k], 1),                              # use a[k] and overshoot
    s[t, k-1] + (0, 1)                      # do not use a[k]
)                         if t < a[k]
```

Once you have filled array `s`, the pair in `(y, j)` in `s[T, 99]` will tell you the lowest target `y` greater than or equal to `t` that is possible, and the number of numbers `j` that is needed to get this target.

To find the combination of numbers that was used, you can retrace the path in the array that was used to build `s[T, 99]` to determine which `a[k]` were used and which were not used.